# Hardware reserved was reserved, fixed by bios update, then after a few restarts goes back top hardware reserved, any indication?

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory, bios, memory-limit

As the title states...

I realized I had half my RAM 8/16gb is being reserved for hardware so I tried a few things, then decided to update my old BIOS. Once updated and a restart it fixed the problem, after a few weeks of use. The computer got weird and wouldn't boot properly, needing system repair (windows). A few attempts at just restarting and it started working again but with the hardware reserved.

My RAM is seen everywhere two sticks receiving electricity and the 2x8gb is recognized. I'm hoping this would give you guys some clue as to where the issue may lie.

SPECS:
AMD Ryzen 5 1600 AF
B450 TOMAHAWK MAX
G.skill 2x8gb DDR4
GTX 1650 Super

Thank you,
Andrew Ricci

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are experiencing some hardware glitches.

I suggest:

- Look in the Event Viewer for more information
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for several hours
- If you can't find any indication of where is the problem, go to a repair-shop.